# ismember only take first number

Tags: matlab

if I have two arrays

```
A=[5 5 7 8]
B=[5 7 7]
```

I want all the positions of the numbers of B that are in A, except if they are dubbled in A, then I only want the first one.
This means I want as output:

```
C=[1 3 3]; %indexes
```

because 5 is in position 1 in A and I only want the first one. The number 7 is in position 3 in array A and occurs twice in array B.
That way:
A(C)=B

I tried the following code, but it only deals with taking the first in case of dubbles in A. It unfortunately also deletes the position of the dubbles in B.

```
[ifM,posfM]=ismember(A,B);%find position where B is in A
nuls=find(posfM==0);%positions where this is not the case
[Ci,iafM,ic] = unique(posfM);% make sure the same number is only selected once (A=[1 1 2 3],B=[1 3] creates three numbers if ismember(A,B) and we only need two) 
posnuls=ismember(iafM,nuls);
iafM(posnuls)=[];
fBM=fMag(iafM);
```

Comment: Have you tried `[~, C]= ismember(B,A)` ?

Comment: @rahnema1 omg that's indeed all it took. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop over `B`, and for each element in B find the index of its first occurence:

```
>> C = arrayfun(@(x) find(A==x,1),B);
```